# How to display a HTML tag in Yii2 form error summary

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model, yii2-validation

I am trying to display a link in error message in login for, but it is not working.

The error message in `LoginForm` valdiation:

```
$this->addError($attribute, 'Your account has been disabled. <a href=""> Enable It</a>');
```

In `login.php` (view):

```
<?= $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
```

I tried like below, but not working:

```
 <?= $form->errorSummary($model,['errorOptions' => ['encode' => false,'class' => 'help-block']]); ?>
```

I am getting the following output instead of rendered `a` tag:

[image: error summary]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to disable encoding at `ActiveForm` level using [`encodeErrorSummary`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activeform#$encodeErrorSummary-detail) property, if you want to use `$form->errorSummary($model)`:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'login-form',
    'encodeErrorSummary' => false,
    'errorSummaryCssClass' => 'help-block',
]) ?>

<?= $form->errorSummary($model) ?>
```

Alternatively you may use [`Html::errorSummary()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#errorSummary()-detail) directly:

```
<?= Html::errorSummary($model, ['encode' => false]) ?>
```

Comment: great!. thank you <?= Html::errorSummary($model, ['encode' => false]) ?> this is working.